# What happens to a thread when an up is done on its mutex?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, critical-section

Mutexes are used to protect critical sections. Let's say a down has been already done on a mutex, and while the thread that did that is in the CS, 10 other threads are right behind it and do a down on the mutex, putting themselves to sleep. When the first thread exits the critical section and does an up on the mutex, do all 10 threads wake up and just resume what they were about to do, namely, entering the critical section? Wouldn't that mean then that all 10 might end up in the critical section at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only *one* thread will wake up and take ownership of the mutex. The rest of them will remain asleep. Which thread is the one that wakes up is usually nondeterministic.

<sup>The above is a generalisation and the details of implementation will be different in each system. For example, in Java compare [Object#notify()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) and [Object#notifyAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29).</sup>

Comment: When that thread wakes up, does it just go on to the next thing it was about to do before going to sleep?

Comment: The next thing it was about to do was to acquire the mutex. If the mutex is available and hasn't already been acquired by something else in the meantime (this can happen), then yes, it will wake up and continue whatever it was doing.

Comment: When multiple processes do down on a mutex, does its value go below 0? Can its value be anything other than 0 or 1?

Comment: @z-buffer: The "value" is a conceptual way of thinking about a mutex, and a given implementation may or may not have a numeric value associated with a mutex. Only one thread may acquire and hold a mutex at any given time. Conceptually, that could mean that the "value" of that mutex can only be 0 or 1.